# Overwrite a bunch of filenames

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have a few folders each containing large filenames that downloaded in a strange naming format and obscures the file extension and I want to convert to something very simple.

Here's an example of what I want to do. Let's say these four files are located in one of the folders:

```
HTTP_services.cgi?FILENAME=%2Fdata%2FMERRA2%2FM2I6NPANA.5.12.4%2F1992%2F08%2FMERRA2_200.inst6_3d_ana_Np.19920818.nc4&FORMAT=bmM0Lw&BBOX=-90%2C-180%2C90%2C180&LABEL=MERRA2_200.inst6_3d_ana_Np.19920818.SUB.nc4&SHORTNAME=M2I6NPANA&SERVICE=
HTTP_services.cgi?FILENAME=%2Fdata%2FMERRA2%2FM2I6NPANA.5.12.4%2F1992%2F08%2FMERRA2_200.inst6_3d_ana_Np.19920819.nc4&FORMAT=bmM0Lw&BBOX=-90%2C-180%2C90%2C180&LABEL=MERRA2_200.inst6_3d_ana_Np.19920819.SUB.nc4&SHORTNAME=M2I6NPANA&SERVICE=
HTTP_services.cgi?FILENAME=%2Fdata%2FMERRA2%2FM2I6NPANA.5.12.4%2F1992%2F08%2FMERRA2_200.inst6_3d_ana_Np.19920820.nc4&FORMAT=bmM0Lw&BBOX=-90%2C-180%2C90%2C180&LABEL=MERRA2_200.inst6_3d_ana_Np.19920820.SUB.nc4&SHORTNAME=M2I6NPANA&SERVICE=
HTTP_services.cgi?FILENAME=%2Fdata%2FMERRA2%2FM2I6NPANA.5.12.4%2F1992%2F08%2FMERRA2_200.inst6_3d_ana_Np.19920821.nc4&FORMAT=bmM0Lw&BBOX=-90%2C-180%2C90%2C180&LABEL=MERRA2_200.inst6_3d_ana_Np.19920821.SUB.nc4&SHORTNAME=M2I6NPANA&SERVICE=
```

I would like these to just be renamed something very basic like

```
1.nc4
2.nc4
3.nc4
4.nc4
```

The new numbers have no relation to the original filenames. I just want to be able to iterate through them easily with another program I have.

I've attempted to use batch renaming programs like pyrenamer and metamorphose but they seem to be good at replacing patterns in names with other patterns, not just overwriting the name with a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple loop:

```
count=0; for file in HTTP_services*; do mv "$file" "$(( count++ )).nc4"; done;
```

use it with an `echo` first to make sure it works as you wish:

```
$ count=0; for file in HTTP_se*; do echo "mv" "$file" "$(( count++ )).nc4"; done;
mv HTTP_services.cgi?FILENAME=%2Fdata%1 1.nc4
mv HTTP_services.cgi?FILENAME=%2Fdata%2 2.nc4
```